# Caliburn.Xamarin.Forms Binding content to a ViewModel

Tags: caliburn.micro, xamarin.forms

With Silverlight/WPF i was able to bind the content of a tabcontrol to a view model using:
`<ContentControl cm:View.Model="{Binding Test}"/>`
I'm trying this with Caliburn and Xamarin Forms and a TabbedPage and my experiment is:

```
<TabbedPage>
    <TabbedPage.Children>
     <ContentPage Title="Test" cm:View.Model="{Binding Test}">
```

This gives no errors but shows nothing on the tab.

I use a:  `((IActivate)Test).Activate();` in my viewmodel to show the content. Somehow a `Start` method is not there...

Can this be done? I sometimes want to reuse this content on other pages as well.
I'm using the latest alpha from Nigel.

Comment: my best guess is some stuff isn't remotely ready and based on his checklist of things that work / confirmed or not it's alpa code https://github.com/Caliburn-Micro/Caliburn.Micro/issues/142

Comment: That functionality should be working in the alpha, do you have a small demo I could look at?

Comment: I tested it with a  contentview on a contentpage and this worked. I will make another test with the tabbed page and the latest bits from github.

Comment: On a TabedPage it works not directly on the ContentPage but a workaround is:
<ContentPage Title="Test">
      <ContentView cm:View.Model="{Binding Test}"/>
By using a ContentView. May be the TabbedPage must be a Conductor with OneActive View...

    </ContentPage>

Comment: John/Nigel, I'm trying to do a TabbedPage with CM as well. Mine's not working. I've set my ItemsSource to a BindableCollection<Screen>. However, CM isn't loading the corresponding Views. Would you mind sharing a more complete example of how you did this?

Comment: Which event is being attached to when invoking ((IActivate)Test).Activate(): ?

Comment: I used a poor mans solution by binding each tab individually, like  <ContentPage Title="{Binding Sections[1].DisplayName}" >
      <ContentView cm:View.Model="{Binding Sections[1]}"/>
    </ContentPage> if you contact me at jkattestaart@gmail.com i can send you some code, but maybe it is outdated now. It was some time ago i worked on it.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I might take you up on that offer for more source code via email but for now I've tried a different approach. It occurred to me that maybe you meant that you had replaced "TabbedPage" with "ContentPage". I did this and used a Grid with the buttons in the bottom row (height="60") in for the tabs . I then used your "ContentView" like a WPF ContentControl in the top row (Height="*") to display the current ActiveItem. I'm really not sure how to use CM correctly with XF. So far I like this approach. I hope they create more documentation and more extensive samples sometime soon.